# Selecting div element with arrow keys in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to navigate through the div elements using arrow keys. I know how to achieve it in JavaScript however I am struggling doing it "vue way". i know there should not be any differences but it simply does not work.

I have made [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v3lyz1pp07) for you to check what is going on. It is working if I am **not using** Vue

In Vue I get the following error because of this line:

> Cannot read property 'focus' of null

```
document.activeElement.parentNode.previousSibling.firstChild.focus();
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Is the `v-for` the error source or are there some other problems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on why you need a `focus`. If it's just to highlight something, you can use a secondary variable to track which one you're currently highlighting and add a class to it instead

https://codesandbox.io/s/300vxzkyk5

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input ref="input" type="text" @keydown="test" tabindex="0">
    <div ref="test" v-for="item, index in items" :class="{ focus: index === focus }">
       <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: "First" },
        { title: "Second" },
        { title: "Third" }
      ],
      focus: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    test: function(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38:
          if (this.focus === null) {
            this.focus = 0;
          } else if (this.focus > 0) {
            this.focus--;
          }
          break;
        case 40:
          if (this.focus === null) {
            this.focus = 0;
          } else if (this.focus < this.items.length - 1) {
            this.focus++;
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
div.focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reverse thinking, it did work for highlighting :D I need highlight to let user know which one he/she is selecting and then I have to get the object after the selection and enter pressed. I am gonna try to get the object also now :)

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp and that should be simple also since the `focus` variable points to the array index, so you can just do `items[focus]` or the like

Comment: Yep, that is what I did. Love this solution

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a data-driven approach to this?

You have an array of items. You can set an active property on each item and toggle that  to `true` or `false`.

Your up and down keys will change the array pointer and set the current pointer item to true. This way you do not have to do any DOM selection.

Comment: yeah, that's the idea I had, much simpler in vue terms